# How to send double click on keyboard focused object from c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, focus, send

the question is how to send double click to object who is already focused by keyboard? For example let's say that my mouse is on bottom right position on screen, if i open explorer by pressing WIN+E, and than press SPACE -> i will get focus to disk (c:\ disk for example), so i want to know on what coordinate is that focus that can send double click to it. Is there any function in c++ that do it for us?

Comment: What is your real goal? To open explorer in a specific folder?

Answer (score 2):

```
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
  Sleep(10); 
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
  Sleep(10); 
  // Click Two 
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
  Sleep(10); 
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

From google:

http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.winapi/browse_thread/thread/f1380942baf5c1ae?pli=1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible - in your example, the Explorer window is highlighting the drive object - you need some way to obtain the coordinates of the object with in the explorer window (which you do not control, right?)

It's not hard to send a double-click to a window - but what is happening within the window is difficult to determine.

Answer (score 0):

You can find currently focused window with `GetFocus` function.  But there's in general no way to find where to send a double click event.  You can easily find out the dimensions and the screen coordinates of any window with `GetWindowRect` function.  You can send that event to the center of the window or to any of its corner or anywhere else, and in some cases that would suffice.

In your example you would need to figure out where the selected element is located on the screen and that element is not a window, its state is maintained by the parent window and generally there's no way to get that information.

Comment: "its state is maintained by the parent window and generally there's no way to get that information," yes if we use getfocus and getwindowrect method but i thought maybe is there some other way to send double click like get position of highlited object looking for changed color on monitor or something like that ...

Comment: There's no general API to get "highlighted object".  Usually it's something application specific.  In case of Explorer it's probably possible to investigate its window hierarchy and find out which type of controls it's using.  After that it could be possible to access those control's internals if they provide such API.  But this technique cannot be done in general for any application.

Comment: yes, thnx in advice, i thought there is no something like this, ... i will have to find some other method ..:)

Comment: nothing yet, but i maybe will take a look at some function which scan color at pixel level, so idea is to get active window, than use getwindowrect function to scan that area and save color information after that wait to key press and rescan after that and see which color is changed value and on that are send click. Theoretically of course :)

Comment: I meant what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's an alternative way to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of mouse, so need some alternative to make faster repetitive keyboard tasks.

Comment: Maybe you should try the command line approach.  Explorer is not very keyboard-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out MSAA or UIAutomation on MSDN; these are APIs that allow you to access element information below the HWND level. They are designed for test tools and accessibility tools that need this information. For example, a screen magnifier can use these APIs to follow the keyboard focus, get the location of the current element, and determine the correct coordinates to zoom in on.

MSAA/UIA are supported widely within Windows - all the system controls (as used in explorer) support it, as does the content of IE, Firefox, and some other apps.

You can use the inspect.exe tool that's part of the Windows SDK to play with this functionality.

Note that before clicking on the target, you should check that the element at that point is the element you expect it to be: if there's some other dialog in the way, the click will go to that element instead.